# Does infiltrator get invisibility cloak in Mass Effect 1?

Tags: mass-effect, mass-effect-series

I played Mass Effect out of order. I started with ME2 (since that was the first one on the PS3 at the time), and now I'm going back to ME1 (since it is also available on PS3 now). In ME2 I chose Infiltrator class because I got an invisibility cloak, which was awesome. I am playing ME1 as infiltrator, but I have no cloak. Will I get one at any point in the game? Or was that an item added in ME2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as invisibility in ME1.  However, if you gain enough levels in Sniper Rifles, you'll gain a skill called Assassination that greatly boosts your next shot somewhat to the bonus you gain with tactical cloak.